# SQLite Stores characters as strings?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using the System.Data.SQLite ADO.Net Provider to interact with an SQLite DB. I used the following syntax to create a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE [tb_Replace] ([Character] CHAR(1), [Substitute] CHAR(1))
```

I then tried to read the data using a simple select:

```
public static List<char> GetReplaceableCharacters(string connectionString)
{
    List<char> replaceableCharacters = new List<char>();
    SQLiteConnection sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);
    sqlConnection.Open();
    using (SQLiteTransaction transaction = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(@"SELECT Character FROM tb_Replace", sqlConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
            replaceableCharacters.Add((char)reader["Character"]);
    }
    sqlConnection.Close();
    return replaceableCharacters;
}
```

However when I did that it threw an InvalidCastException. However, if I change the return type to a`List<string>` and cast `reader["Character"]` to a string it works. Does anyone know why this would be?

Comment: Taylor `Well, string is IEnumerable<char>` so for example to could declare something like the following ` `List<char> someChars = new List<char>();`
            `var someCharArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToList();` then apply this to your example hope this gives you an idea on how to use `List<char>` also it may help if you show an example of what the SQL Select statement returns so we can see what the data looks like..Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just read http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.

Sqlite has five type affinities (types *preferred* by a column of a table) and five storage classes (possible actual value types). There is no `CHARACTER` type among either of them.

Sqlite allows you to specify just about *anything* as a type for column creation. But it doesn't enforce types for everything except `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` columns. It recognizes a few *substring* of declared type names to determine column type affinity, so `CHARACTER`, `CHARCOAL` and `CONTEXTUALIZABLE` are all just a funny way of writing `TEXT`.